# jQuery Input value not returned when submit

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input

[Noob question] I'm using contact form 7 from Wordpress. I have 2 inputs which I have to return post_title and price for event :

```js
if (window.location.href.indexOf("event") > -1) {
  var titre = $('.entry-title').text();
  var prix = $('.ai1ec-cost .ai1ec-field-value').text();

  $('.ghost input').prop('disabled', true);
  $('.ghost input').attr('value', titre);
  $('.ghost input').val(titre);

  $('.ghostPrice input').prop('disabled', true);
  $('.ghostPrice input').val(prix);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/event/pause-cafe-des-parents/?instance_id=35#wpcf7-f1623-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
  <label class="ghost"> Nom de l'événement<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap evenement">
      <input name="evenement" value="la pause-café" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" disabled="" type="text">
    </span>
  </label>
  <label class="ghostPrice"> Prix de l'événement<br>
    <i>Les modalités de paiements seront présents dans l'e-mail de confirmation</i><br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap price">
      <input name="price" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" disabled="" type="text">
    </span>
  </label>
  <p>
     <input value="Envoyer" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" type="submit"><span class="ajax-loader"></span>
  </p>
</form>
```

My input return my value correctly but when I submit my form, this value not returned.

If I type in my input (like normal form), my value is returned.

Any idea ?

Comment: `ghostPrice`, where is it?

Comment: There are a few details missing in the questions like inputs you are using and where you are submitting the form.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 ghost price is like the another label :) (same but only class change)

Comment: @bhansa Post edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just removed "disabled" and add "hide" and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Remove disabled  attribute from the inputs